# Spring StringToObject.toObject() not called on list?

Tags: java, spring, type-conversion

So we're using probably quite an old style of Spring property conversion. Basically when a page loads it converts the entity objects into their id values, then when the page submits it takes the id value, looks up the entity object by that id and populates it back.

Example is below;

```
import org.springframework.binding.convert.converters.StringToObject;

public class StringToExamVO extends StringToObject {

    private VerifyService verifyService;

    public StringToExamVO(VerifyService verifyService) {
        super(ExamVO.class);
        this.verifyService = verifyService;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Object object) {
        ExamVO spec = (ExamVO) object;
        return (spec != null && spec.getId() != null ? spec.getId().toString() : null);
    }

    @Override
    public Object toObject(String string, Class targetClass) {
        if (string != null && string.length() > 0 && targetClass.equals(ExamVO.class)) {
            String id = StringUtils.trimToNull(string);
            return verifyService.loadExam(Integer.decode(id));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now this works great if our form backing command has a single entity property;

```
private ExamVO exam;

public void setExam(ExamVO exam) {
  this.exam = exam;
}

public ExamVO getExam() {
  return this.exam;
}
```

However it doesn't appear to work if the property is a LIST of the entities, eg;

```
private List<ExamVO> exams;

public void setExams(List<ExamVO>exam) {
  this.exams = exams;
}

public List<ExamVO> getExams() {
  return this.exams;
}
```

Following through the debugger for the single property type (first example) I can see both toString and toObject get called on page load and page submit respectively.

However debugging when the property is a LIST, only the toString is called (repeatedly cos its a list). On page submit, there is no call to toObject, meaning I guess its not even trying to convert the string ids back into entity objects.

Putting a breakpoint in the `getExams` list property getter I can even see that although the list is defined as `List<ExamVO>` the `ExamVO` objects that were in their index slots are being overwritten with `Strings`!

Is the Spring conversion framework unable to detect that since its populating a `List<ExamVO>` then it probably should call the toObject method of the `StringToExamVO` converter for each slot??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about this some more, in regards to my question at the bottom which basically reads;

"Can Spring detect its populating a List, ie a list with a generic type, and therefore call to converter to convert the String into the ExamVO generic type"

I believe the answer is NO, because generic typing is stripped out at runtime. So at runtime the List is just a List with no typing, which is why Spring can insert Strings into it rather than ExamVOs and also why the conversion service doesn't get called, as without the generic typing the framework doesn't know the list is suppose to contain ExamVOs.

I have now changed the way my code works but did breifly toy with the following idea;

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<ExamVO> getExams() {
    if(Exams == null) {
        exams = new ArrayList() {

            @Override
            public ExamVO set(int index, Object element) {
                // TODO if element is a String, 
                // call the verifyService.loadExam(Integer.decode(element));
                // to get the ExamVO and set that to element
                return (ExamVO)super.set(index, element);
            }
        };
    }
    return exams;
}
```

This in theory would work however having that call into the service layer from a command/form backing object seems quite iffy to me.